# A Question Regarding Diagonalization

Tags: elementary-set-theory

For this question I am only considering binary sequences of countably infinite length.

Consider an arbitrary set $S$ of such sequences, $S$ of order type omega, $\omega$.  By diagonalization one can construct a binary sequence $s_*$ not contained in $S$. Add $s_*$ to $S$ to form a new set, call it $S'$, of countable order type $\omega+1$.  Now it would seem that one can diagonalize out of $S'$ and construct another binary sequence, call it $s_*'$ ($s_*'$ of order type $\omega$) contained in neither $S$ nor $S'$ and continue this process until the order type of the set formed by the operations of diagonalization and adding the diagonal (which is always of order type $\omega$) to the set is at least $\omega_1$.

Can this process be continued past $\omega_1$?  If not, why not?  If yes, then how?

Comment: A COMMENT REGARDING WRITING TITLES USING ONLY CAPITAL LETTERS.

Comment: is this a corollary of the continuum hypothesis?

Comment: Whether you can or not is independent of the usual axioms of set theory. See [continuum hypothesis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum_hypothesis).

Comment: I think lower case with normal capitalization fairly prevalent and is far easier to read.

Comment: Now, if the continuum hypothesis holds, whether you can continue or not depends on how the terms you keep adding are chosen. Under this assumption, sometimes you can continue, and sometimes you cannot.

Comment: I am not sure the CH answers are really relevant. The question is whether or not one can find a sequence outside of $S$ (the one with order type $\omega_1$) using *diagonalization*, not just whether or not such a sequence exists.

Comment: @DanShved CH is *obviously* relevant: If it fails, the answer is always yes. If it holds, the answer depends on the specifics of the diagonalization process.

Comment: @DanShved We are basically in agreement, but you are misunderstanding what I am saying.

Comment: @Andres You are right, looks like I have missed the end of your original comment.

Comment: @Andres: You can continue, but not through diagonalization, since that would result in a sequence of length $\omega_1$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yes, so what? What you cannot ever do under $\mathsf{CH}$ is to reach $\omega_2$, but for any ordinal $\alpha$ below $\omega_2$ you can arrange the process so it goes past $\alpha$.

Comment: @Andres: I might be missing something subtle here. If the process is "diagonalize against everything you have so far", and diagonalization takes a countable set of sequences to produce another; how would you diagonalize at the next step? Will you consider countable subsets now instead? I mean, what would be the method from which you procure the next sequence?

Comment: @AsafKaragila You are fixing bijections $\alpha\to\omega$ for each $alpha<\omega_1$, and when the type of your functions is $\alpha\ge\omega$, you rearrange them in type $\omega$ using the $\alpha$-th bijection, and diagonalize against the resulting sequence.

Comment: @Andres: Obviously, but what about steps $\alpha\geq\omega_1$?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Ah, silly me! Take your favorite countable subsequence, and diagonalize against.

Comment: @Andres: But why would that work (especially with my "favorite subsequence")? I mean, we already have uncountably many sequences. What assures me that the subsequence will produce a fresh new real number? I mean, the mapping $\langle r_n\mid n\in\omega\rangle\mapsto r$, where $r$ is the diagonalized sequence is not even injective (flip the $n+1$ bit from $r_n$ and the result is still the same). I don't see why without planning ahead we can assure that whatever sequence I chose as my favorite sequence will produce a new real number which is not in the previous $\aleph_1$ that I have.

Comment: @AsafKaragila It may not work without the planning ahead, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, when you say "order type" it implies that there is a natural order on the sequences. That doesn't necessary happen. Moreover the resulting sequence from the diagonal argument need not be larger in the order that you chose.

But suppose that you begin with a countable set, then using diagonalization you add more and more elements. Can you go beyond $\omega_1$? Well, not necessarily. If the continuum hypothesis holds, or if we are in a context of $\sf ZF$ and $\aleph_1\nleq2^{\aleph_0}$, then it might be the case that your process has exhausted itself somehow.

Either by showing that this inductive method is insufficient to define a set of size $\aleph_1$ (i.e. we have to make some uncountably many choices (in the context of $\sf ZF$ it might be the case that going through all the $\omega_1$ steps requires a scale to $\omega_1$, that is a sequence of enumerations for all the countable ordinals, which may not exist without the axiom of choice); or that we simply lucked out and managed to cover all the real numbers, in the case that $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_1$, in which case you can't continue anymore.

If you could have proved from $\sf ZF(C)$ that diagonalization carries to ordinals of size $\aleph_1$, then you would have proved $\lnot\sf CH$ and so the inconsistency of $\sf ZFC$. However if we assume more, e.g. $\sf MA+\lnot CH$, then we can switch to other techniques to produce newer sequences.

Comment: Given your statement, "However, if we assume more, e.g. MA+ not-CH , then we can switch to other techniques to produce newer sequences", does this imply that there are principles of infinitary combinatorics independent of ZF(C) one could assume as new axioms that would allow diagonalization to continue past omega_1?

Comment: Thomas, assuming $\sf MA+\lnot CH$ one can show that in a c.c.c forcing of size $\aleph_1$, every collection of $\aleph_1$ dense sets admits a generic within the universe. So one can use that as a form of an extended diagonalization. Consider the Cohen forcing, all finite binary sequences ordered by extension, it's a c.c.c. forcing of size $\aleph_0$. Given $\{f_\alpha\mid\alpha<\omega_1\}$ we can define $D_\alpha$ to be the sequences which differ from an initial segment of $f_\alpha$. Easily the $D_\alpha$ are dense. By $\sf MA$ we have a generic for those dense sets, which is a new sequence.

Comment: To the editor: I am trying to use MathJax in my comment to Asaf.  Unfortunately, it was so garbled that he couldn't read it (as you can see by his comment).  Please be so kind as to show me how to write in boldface 'MA +not-CH',  and 'omega_1' in MathJax so as to not have this problem in the future.  I was following your quick tutorial but am not getting the desired results.  Thanks.

Comment: Could forcing itself be properly construed as as a generalization of diagonalization in that it 'constructs' new reals or sets?

Comment: @Thomas: That's an extremely vague question. Diagonalization works within the universe, forcing extends the universe. The point of Martin's axiom is that it ensures that the universe contains some sets which are "a little generic" in the sense that they meet a lot of dense sets, but not all of them of course.

Comment: Is the notion of, say, 'adding a real' in forcing arguments distinct from the intuitive notion of 'constructing a real'? How so?  It would seem (at least to me) to be so in the naturalistic account of forcing.

Comment: Thomas, it seems to me that you are trying to understand gist of forcing and other advanced set theoretical ideas without actually understanding them. That can be a problem, since the jargon of set theory (and of mathematics in general) have words which may give the wrong idea to people unfamiliar with it. I'm not sure what you mean by "naturalistic account of forcing" either.

Comment: First, a correction.  I meant to say that in the naturalistic account of forcing, 'adding a real' seems to me identical to the intuitive notion of 'constructing a real, and that constructing a real always produces a new real so that constructing a real always extends the set of reals.  As regards the notion of the "naturalistic account of forcing", this notion comes from Joel David Hamkins' multiverse view of set theory.  It attgempts to answer positively the question of whether forcing extensions of the set-theoretic universe V exist.  As you know, in a countable transitive model

Comment: It seems to me that at least one of us doesn't have a full understanding of Hamkins "Naturalist Account of Forcing". And it would seem to me that you're using that term wrong in your previous comment where this first came up. Set theory, as any other modern mathematical field, is very very very very very very difficult to comprehend from far away, just by trying to scheme through terms and papers. You have to actually sit and prove things before you can understand any of it in a reasonable way.

Comment: of ZFC, one can construct an M-generic filter G by diagonalization.  The naturalistic account of forcing, according to Hamkins, allows one to make the move from forcing over a model M to forcing over the universe V.  What Hamkins holds is that supposing that V is a universe of set theory and P is a notion of forcing, there is a class model of the theory (ZFC) expressing what it means to be the corresponding forcing extension. "Namely, the theory keep everything in V, relativised to a class predicate, and also asserts that there is a V-generic filter." (this a direct quote from Hamkins'

Comment: talk, "The set-theoretic multiverse:  a model-theoretic philosophy of set theory."

Comment: How was I using 'naturalistic account of forcing' incorrectly in my original comment regarding it?